# Is there anything wrong with the following proof?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Question 1: 
We define $d_2:\mathbb{R^2}\times \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ by $((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) \rightarrow ((x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$
Prove that $(\mathbb{R^2},d_2)$ is a metric space.

Answer: For $ d_2:\mathbb{R^2}\times \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ to be a metric space the following properties must hold:

1. $d_2((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) =0$ iff $x_1=y_1, x_2=y_2$
   Then $d_2((x_1,x_2),(x_1,x_2))=((x_1-x_1)^2+(x_2-x_2)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=0$
2. $d_2(x,y)=d_2(y,x), \forall x,y\in X$ or in this case 
   $$d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=((x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=((x_1^2-2x_1*y_1+y_1^2)+((x_2^2-2x_2*y_2+y_2^2))^{\frac{1}{2}}=((y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=d((y_1,y_2),(x_1,x_2))$$
3. $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z), \forall x,y,z\in X$ or in this case $$d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))+d((z_1,x_2),(z_1,y_2))=((x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}+((y_1-z_1)^2+(y_2-z_2)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\geq ((x_1-z_1)^2+(x_2-z_2)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$  $\iff $ $$ \|x-y\|_2+ \|y-z\|_2\geq \|x-z\|_2$$ $\iff$ $$\|x-y\|_2+ \|y-z\|\geq \|(x-y)+(y-z)\|_2$$ which holds by the Minkowski inequality. 
   Note: I tryed to retain as much as possible any minor slips I did while writing this. Everything is exactly as I wrote it on paper. I do not understand what I have done wrong. We were allowed to use the Minkowski inequality since it was proven in previous lectures. I used bold for the vector notation in part 3 in here. Other notation is used in the original text but it is perfectly clear.

Comment: Ask the instructor, not us.

Comment: Well the issue is that I think this answer is mathematically correct and this is what I want to know before asking. If the way I posed the question is wrong please say so so that I will correct it. You can ascertain the mathematical truth of a proof

Comment: 1- Should be $d( (x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)) \geq 0$ with equality iff $x_1 = y_1, x_2 = y_2$. So, you need to show that $ \sqrt{ (x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2}$ indeed satisfies this.

Comment: Thx yes indeed but doesnt saying that $d((x1,x2),(x1,x2))=0$ imply the equality part? Or is there a case when this is not true?

Comment: It is almost trivial alright, but I'd demonstrate why it holds! $d( (x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)) \geq 0$ because the square root of nonnegative real numbers is nonnegative. And $\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2} = 0 \implies (x_1-y_1)^2  = -(x_2 - y_2)^2$, but square of real numbers is positive, hence $x_1 - y_1 = x_2-y_2 = 0$, and conversely.

Comment: Yes this is what I thought thanks a lot.